# Dynamic Table using jQuery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to create a Dynamic Table using jQuery Template plugin.

My requirement is that columns are created dynamically i.e. there is a ListBox with ColumnNames... when item is clicked it should create a table with that column and when another item is clicked it should update the existing template and add the second column and so on...

I am trying with the following code sample but no luck...

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 8px;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            width:600px;
            overflow:scroll;
        }
        table td
        {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="showColBtn">
        CreateColumn</button><br />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr id="tblOrderReportHeaderRow">
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tblOrderReportBody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var markup = "";
        var arrTableHeader = [];

        /* Render the Column Name template */
        $("#showColBtn").click(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                markup += createHeaderMarkup();
                arrTableHeader.push(createHeader("Col" + i));
            }
            /* Compile markup string as a named template */
            $.template("tblHeaderTemplate", markup);

            $("#tblOrderReportHeaderRow").empty();
            $.tmpl("tblHeaderTemplate", arrTableHeader).appendTo("#tblOrderReportHeaderRow");
        });

        function createHeaderMarkup() {
            return ("<th colspan='2'>${colName}</th>");

        }

        function createHeader(colName) {

            return ({ 'colName': colName });

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a prototype on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Here is the link to sample :http://jsfiddle.net/UVtNw/

Comment: I have updated my sample @ http://jsfiddle.net/UVtNw/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UVtNw/3/ 
I have got it 2 work but now each column s being displayed 11 times
Any help

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but i've fixed your jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pixeline/UVtNw/6/

Comment: I was trying to create dynamic columns on click of options from a select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing  **markup += createHeaderMarkup();** from for loop